# "Die Farbe Pink" – groß- oder kleinschreiben?

Tags: capitalization

Folgende Satzkonstellation:

> "Das Produkt ist erhältlich in der Farbe Pink"

("Pink" natürlich ersetzbar durch jede andere Farbe.)

Wird die Farbe hier groß- oder kleingeschrieben? Es ist ja "die Farbe xx", klingt irgendwie so, als werde die Farbe hier als Nomen verwendet; andererseits ist pink ja eigentlich ein Adjektiv.

Comment: Famous example: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Farbe_Lila_(Film)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die Großschreibung ist korrekt. Farbbezeichnungen werden immer großgeschrieben. Ausnahmen sind natürlich feststehende Wendungen.

Siehe auch [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Nominalisierung.html):

> die Farbe Blau
>   Grün entsteht wenn Gelb und Blau gemischt werden.
>   Das Kleid ist in Lindengrün und in Himmelblau erhältlich.
>   Er fuhr bei Rot über die Kreuzung.
>   Sie trug ihr kleines Schwarzes.

Comment: "Farbbezeichnungen werden immer großgeschrieben" — das ist nicht ganz richtig; eine Farbbezeichnung kann auch ein Adjektiv sein, wie etwa in "der blaue Himmel" oder "die grüne Wiese". Und speziell in "Sie trug ihr kleines Schwarzes" ist "Schwarzes" ein substantiviertes Adjektiv, und wegen der Substantivierung großgeschrieben, nicht wegen der Farbigkeit.

Answer (score 3):

Als Adjektiv verwendet werden Farben klein geschrieben, bei Nominalisierung groß.
*Deshalb:* Wenn du nicht gerade die Farbe an sich meinst, schreibst du "pink" klein.

Angemerkt sei an dieser Stelle, dass Pink/pink ein Lehnwort aus Englischen ist, und **Rosa/rosa** das im alten Sinne korrekte Wort ist.